# iOS 6 app running on iOS 7 style adherence

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios7

I have a CRUD-style app targeted for iOS 6 and I want to know what will happen when my app run under iOS 7. Will it's default controls (textareas, labels, buttons, etc...) adhere the "flat-design" style?

Is there a way to mark like "I'm targeting you, my app, to iOS 6 and if you're running on iOS 6 use 'old-style', but if you're running on iOS 7 use 'new-style'"???

I would like that my app to have the "look'n feel" of the iOS it's running on...

Comment: At the very least, you should read the `iOS 7 Transition Guide` (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html) which will tell you what you will likely have to change to seamlessly support iOS 7. If you're already using Autolayout you will be a long way towards that already.

Answer (score 2):

The standard system controls will be for the version of the iOS you are running, so buttons and textfields will be new, tableview cells will lay out wider etc.

If you've customised any of these then your customisation will apply.

However, some elements are differently sized, so they may be positioned differently depending on how you have laid them out.

It's a good idea to install Xcode5 and run your app through the simulator at least, just to see what it looks like, or whether there are any glitches.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I don't want sound rude, but can you provide any documentation on the matter? i'm trying to make a case on my workplace

Answer (score 2):

If you've used standard iOS controls with not many extra tweaks (tint color etc) then they'll look like flat controls on iOS7, and current style on iOS6.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I don't want sound rude, but can you provide any documentation on the matter? i'm trying to make a case on my workplace

Comment: Do you have access to the iOS prerelease developer section? There's a guide from Apple showing a sample application that runs on both. Unfortunately due to NDA I can't (I think) post the link directly here.